# extracting the type in a template class for use in other templates

Tags: c++, templates, types

How do I extract the template type from a class:

for example,  I have a class like:

```
template <typename T, typename T2 = def>
class A
{
    typedef T type;
    typedef T2 type2;
    //other stuff
}
```

And I want to use `type2` in other templates:

```
template <typename G>
foo(A<G> a)
{
    //This doesn't work:
    std::vector<a::type2> vec;

    //Neither does this:
    std::vector<a->type2> vec;

    //or this:
    std::vector<typename a::type2> vec;

}
```

So how do I figure out what `type2` is for the instance `a` (can `a` have a value for `type2` that isn't the default)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
std::vector<typename A<G>::type2> vec;
```

*Reason*: `std::vector` expects a complete type as its argument, and just `A` is a `template`, but `A<G>` becomes a complete type. From your example, I have mentioned `A<G>`, but it can be `A<int>`, `A<char>` anything.

Comment: sorry, I've clarified my question.  I want the type of a specific instance... is that possible?

Comment: @AndrewSpott, no that's not possible. But why do you want like that ? `a` is an object of `A<G>`, not a type. Ultimately, `type2` belongs to `A<...>`, so it `type2` has to be extracted from where it belongs.

Comment: @AndrewSpott: The nested type is a property of the *type*, not the instance. There is no *type of an specific instance*, but rather a type for the class that the instance belongs to.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I thought that the "class the instance belongs to" is a type?

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports it, you can use the `decltype` feature to name the type of an object.

```
template <typename G>
void foo(A<G> a)
{
    std::vector<typename decltype(a)::type2> vec;
}
```

In this example, `decltype(a)` is the type `A<G>`.